# Why cfx run installs always an old copy of the extension

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I followed [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_started#Packaging_the_add-on) and then I made some changes (I added a sidebar which opens an HTML placed in the data folder). I executed "cfx run" and it worked, but now I'm just modifying the HTML and the changes are never displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! The problem was the root directory preserved an older copy of the generated xpi. I removed it and now changes are displayed.